# SlidingDrawer without handle and sliding actions to content

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to use `SlidingDrawer` in my application. But I have to hide the `handle` and have to show *20%* of the content to be visible when `SlidingDrawer` is closed. 
Also I wants to assign all the *sliding(touch or drag)* actions of the `handle` to `content`. Please help me if any one is having some solution for this.

Please refer the following code snippet which I tried.

```
<View
    android:id="@id/handle"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sliding_drawer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sliding_drawer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sliding_drawer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and Here is my activity:

```
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.graphics.Color;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;
     import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener;
     import android.widget.SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener;

     public class SlidingDrawerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {

            public void onDrawerClosed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });

        drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {

            public void onDrawerOpened() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                drawer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });

        View content = drawer.getContent();
        content.setClickable(true);
        content.setTouchDelegate(drawer.getHandle().getTouchDelegate());
    }
}
```

Here I am able to hide the `handle` by setting `width=0dip`, but unable to know how to show *20%* of content when `SlidingDrawer` is closed and set the actions to the `Content` of the `SlidingDrawer`.

I tried getting the `touchDelegate` of the handle and setting it to `Content`, but it does not work.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Raj, Cool concept! :). Can you please post some code what you have written or at what point you failed to achieve it. Everyone is here more than happy to help you.

Comment: Hi Abhilasha,I've updated my post. Please check that and help me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

To have a slidingDrawer without handle, the trick is just set the width and height of the handle to 0dp. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the current SlidingDrawer unless you are dealing with something that can be cut and separated into that 20%.  If you look at the source for SlidingDrawer, specifically `open()` you'll see that it calls a private method, `openDrawer()`.  Here's what that does:

```
private void openDrawer() {
    moveHandle(EXPANDED_FULL_OPEN);
    mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (mExpanded) {
        return;
    }

    mExpanded = true;

    if (mOnDrawerOpenListener != null) {
        mOnDrawerOpenListener.onDrawerOpened();
    }
}
```

As you can see the content (the "drawer") isn't visible until the handle starts to move.  There doesn't appear to be a hook into when the drawer is moving, only when it starts or ends, so you wouldn't be able to dynamically update what was in the handle or drawer.

If you were dealing with an image, you could cut it into two parts, 20% and 80%.  But since you are working with 3 TextViews it doesn't look like that is an option.

Given that I think an option would be taking the source of SlidingDrawer and creating your own class.  That way you would have full control over how drawing was handled, but still be able to re-use all of the listeners.  Here's a link to the source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java

Answer (score 0):

I am going to do something like you do.

As Slidedrawer is deprecated now, I used custom slidedraw named MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer.
Here is the code I find on internet: [MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer Source Code](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/)

To show content view as a handle, I am not going to hide handle but the content.
I set content view's height is 0 dip

```
<it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    custom:handle="@+id/handle"
    custom:content="@+id/content"
    custom:direction="topToBottom"
    custom:animateOnClick="false"
    custom:allowSingleTap="false"

    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <!--
        paste your content here
        -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
```

As my drawer start from top, I calculate top offset in **onMeasure**

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec )
{
    int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( widthMeasureSpec );
    int widthSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );

    int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( heightMeasureSpec );
    int heightSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );

        if ( widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ) { throw new RuntimeException(
            "SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions" ); }

        final View handle = mHandle;
        measureChild( handle, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );

        //Custom top offset
        int intHandleHeight = handle.getHeight();
        mTopOffset = intHandleHeight*80*-1/100;

        if ( mVertical ) {
            int height = heightSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredHeight() - mTopOffset;
            mContent.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( widthSpecSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
        } else {
            int width = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - mTopOffset;
            mContent.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( heightSpecSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
        }

        setMeasuredDimension( widthSpecSize, heightSpecSize );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something very similar. Have you had any luck?

For showing 20% of the content when SlidingDrawer is closed I recommend using SemiClosedSlidingDrawer. I believe this is where I originally found it: http://pastebin.com/FtVyrcEb.

Also, I have added this in my attr.xml file in res/values/

```
<!-- SemiClosedSlidingDrawer -->
<declare-styleable name="SemiClosedSlidingDrawer">
    <attr name="handle" format="integer" />
    <attr name="content" format="integer" />
    <attr name="topOffset" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="bottomOffset" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="allowSingleTap" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="animateOnClick" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="semiClosedOrientation" format="string" />
    <attr name="semiClosedContentSize" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```